# Python algorithm on Letter-Based Representation of All-Pairwise Comparisons

Tags: python, permutation, anova, tukey

is there anything existing in Python to get the Letters after some pairwise testing such as in the R package multcompView there is the multcompLetter from Piepho 2004: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1391186?

Basically I have a lot of pairwise booleans from a test and would like to build my letters based on those with Python.

Edit.

So I want to produce the letters in the second figure: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/84-tukey-test/

this is an example of my data after the test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[ 0.13 ], [ 0.094], [ 0.68 ],[ 0.042],[ 0.],[ 0.091],[ 0.   ],[ 0.05 ],[ 0.225],[ 0.029]],index = ['d1-d2','d1-d3','d1-d4', 'd1-d5', 'd2-d3', 'd2-d4', 'd2-d5', 'd3-d4', 'd3-d5', 'd4-d5'],columns = ['p-value'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have a specific question about code you have written or an issue you have found implementing code, please provide a **[mcve]**. At a minimum, give an example of your expected input and output, and share your existing logic. This way we are more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks! I added some data and an example